# Powerpoint compatibility in ubuntu and windows

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have made power point presentation using ubuntu. 
Now, I want to open same file in windows XP or windows 7. How can I do it?
Does simply copying the file in windows and opening with Microsoft power point solves problem?

Comment: this has barely to do with the OS...! -- you will get the best results if you use a standardized format like [`.odf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) (`.odp` in the case of a presentation) and then use a office suite which also reads them correct like [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) for example! (ms office can read them, but in most cases not completely correct...)

Answer (score 1):

You probably made the file in LibreOffice Impress which can potentially save in a format that Office Powerpoint does not like(e.x. odp,otp). Check the file extension, it should be something like .ppt or .pptx. Just save in the proper format and you should be fine. You can cahnge the format when using File -> Save As. Select ppt in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to a Power Point Presentation, which makes me think that you already created a `.ppt` or `.pps` file.

The short answer is "YES", these files will run in Power Point for Windows (any version).

If you haven't yet created the `.ppt` or `.pps` file just proceed to save it in the proper format by using the File/Save As option from the Menu, after which you can choose which format you are going to use for the saved file, then you can simply copy/paste your file into any Windows based system (perhaps via USB or any other way) in order to enjoy your presentations.

LibreOffice/OpenOffice Presentations will run in Windows based systems if you install/already have installed the proper piece of software on them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is NO!

You can open a presentation made in MsOffice in Linux programs like LibreOffice, OpenOffice or other but the design of the presentation is lost. The same goes for making a presentation in Linux and exporting it to MsOffice. You can start over with the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

The question is from 2011. Since then, Linux office suites made a lot of progress, and now in 2017, I see an impressive match between LibreOffice and PowerPoint.

Where you can run into problems is:

- Fonts - make sure you either use the fonts distributed with your target system by default, or embed the fonts in the .ppt file, or at least distribute them togeter.
- Animations, which were not documented too well by Microsoft so the implementations may differ.
- Embedded videos which may use some codec not present on the target system.
- Advanced features like forms. Typically, the clones like LibreOffice will alert you if that's the case.

Comment: There's probably room to improve this answer with more detailed info about the current state of compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

A friend did  a couple of slides using libre office impress that had to run in a windows computer with MS Office. All of her animations where gone (in the windows computer), and not all the colors and fonts where the same as in her initial design in impress. You can open files but the compatibility is still far from perfect. So I suggest using a pdf or maybe a .pps like some users above commented.
If you have internet connection during the presentation, you could use google docs or prezi (I never tried prezi, but the feedback from users is good).

Answer (score 0):

No, its too bad. Whats Needed is a small viewer app like powerpoint has, so impress could run on Windows. I find impress easier to use, more intuitive (not completely tho) than powerpoint. Instead you must export impress to PDF then use one of the PDF apps to join these PDF images into one document. Dont forget to set the export to landscape. features like fonts and animation will be lost. so I always bring my linux laptop to the presentation. Consider Wine or Virtualbox and make Powerpoint slides to start. I spent weekends trying to

Comment: The  "small viewer app like PowerPoint has" (Microsoft PowerPoint Viewer) works in Wine but will be retired by Microsoft in April, 2018. That's only 3 months from now.